# Three.js: geometry.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been messing around with [Threejs](http://threejs.org/) trying to get my sea legs, but I've run into a problem long before I expected to and I can't figure out if there's a mistake in my code or a mistake in the framework (I assume it's mine).

I want to replace an object with another when a button is pressed. My test code (below) loads a cube on the initial load, and I was hoping to replace it with a sphere when a button is pressed. However, that's not happening, and instead I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: geometry.addEventListener is not a function
geometry.addEventListener( 'dispose', onGeometryDispose );
```

My html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>My test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.js"></script>
  <script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
  <script>
      var WIDTH = 500,
         HEIGHT = 500;
      var scene = new THREE.Scene();
      var aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspect, 0.1, 1000);
      camera.position.set(0,0,5);
      scene.add(camera);
      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize( WIDTH , HEIGHT );
      document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

      var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 ); 
      var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial(); 
      var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ); 
      scene.add( cube ); 

      controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        controls.update();
      }
      animate();


    </script>
    <div>
        <button onclick="updateThing();">Update Thing</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</html>
```

My function for making the change when the button is pressed:

```
function updateThing() {
    scene.remove(cube)
    var pos = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0); 
    var geo = new THREE.Sphere(pos, parseFloat(1.4));
    var mat = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geo, mat );
    scene.add( sphere );
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Orbit controls can be found here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `THREE.SphereGeometry` instead of `THREE.Sphere`:

```
var geo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(parseFloat(1.4));
```

See documentation [here](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/SphereGeometry) and [here](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Sphere).

Comment: Yup, that was indeed it. So obvious now, as always with stupid mistakes.